# High level aggregation

Tags: hadoop, hive

Any one can explain me/provide me a link reg. that, what is high level aggregation is?
I read some where that setting the property

```
  hive.map.aggr = true
```

performs **high-level aggregation**. But i couldn't find the meaning of it!

Answer (score 1):

hive.map.aggr controls how we do aggregations. The default is false. If it is set to true, Hive will do the first-level aggregation directly in the map task.
This usually provides better efficiency, but may require more memory to run successfully.

https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-groupby.html#LanguageManualGroupBy-MapsideAggregationforGroupBy

further discussion:
http://dev.bizo.com/2013/02/map-side-aggregations-in-apache-hive.html

Answer (score -2):

Answer is in [HIVE Programming](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9781449326944), page 86. GL!